# I need a new bike derailleur, which one?

Tags: derailleur, replacement

I have a fairly old Specialized Hardrock Sport.

I want to get new derailleurs. Is there a specific one I should get. I'm not sure the one now is the original.

Comment: We need more info, specifically: number of chainrings, number of sprockets in the rear cluster, number of teeth on largest and smallest chairings,  number of teeth on largest and smallest sprockets. Presumably derailleurs and shifters are Shimano. Photos of derailleurs and shifters will help.

Comment: Also, the reason why you want new derailleurs. Something broke? You want an upgrade? Etc.

Comment: Forgive me if you already know this, but cables and housing require periodic maintenance. Gunk gets in the housing and the cables stretch, so the shifting degrades over time. If your shifting is poor, you may just need a tune up. New derailleurs would be if something is damaged or you actually want to upgrade (and by then, you could be in need of new shifters and cassette, and possibly a new hub also).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Specialized built bikes with that name from 1993-2010. A lot changed over that time.

In the last year the bike was produced, it had a triple crankset (and presumably before). Triple chainrings are less popular these days, so your choices for a front derailleur will be limited.

For the rear derailleur, you'll need to find something compatible with A) the shifter, and B) the number of sprockets. This will come down to the derailleur's "cable pull ratio," and without knowing more about your specific bike, it's not possible to make a recommendation. Even with that information, it may take some archeology to dig up the right answer.

What is the specific problem you hope to solve by getting new derailleurs? There may be a different solution.

Comment: Building on this answer, a bike this old may benefit from a derailer overhaul. The jockey wheels may need outright replacement by now. If the bike hasn't otherwise been serviced, the shifter and brake cables will also need replacement. https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-overhaul

Comment: Bit of FUD there on the triple - they still exist, less common on road but Shimano still make Deore triples.  Sure they're not trendy, but definitely available.